# Mongodb : select all the questions which has no user record and delete it

Tags: mongodb

Development server:

I have two tables `users` and `questions`, `user_id` is stored in each question.

Unintentionally I have deleted some users, now I want delete questions for which the user doesn't exist,

```
delete from questions where q.id not in( select q.id from questions q inner join users u on u.id = q.user_id);
```

I think the above query does that in mysql but I want to do that in mongodb.

I am new to mongodb I know lookup aggregate function does the join but I don't how to do the above query.

Answer (score 1):

A `$lookup` is indeed needed for this, but you need another pipeline stage, which is `$match` to get only those documents where the `userId` count is `0` (we do *not* want to have documents in our result set where the length of `userId` is `> 0` as this means that the `user_id` exists in `users`).

With the result set from the `aggregation`, you can do a simple iteration and `remove` all docs which remain in the set.
Something like this should do it (since I cannot test it right now, maybe give it a quick test run though):

```
db.getCollection('questions').aggregate([{
            "$lookup": {    
                "from": "users",
                "localField": "user_id",
                "foreignField": "user_id",
                "as": "userId"    
            }
        }, {
            "$match": {
                "userId": {
                    "$size": 0
                }
            }
        },

    ]).forEach((doc) => {
        db.getCollection("questions").remove({ "_id": doc._id });
    });
```

Instead of the `forEach` in the last part, you also get all the `id`s and remove them in one single `remove`-query like Ravi did.

Comment: I am doing it in the mongo server.

Comment: This should be fine - for a quick  test you can remove the `forEach`-loop and check the result of the aggeration first.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will have to use `$lookup` and `aggregation` pipeline to get all the questions where the user does not exist and then delete those questions.

Try this:

```
var pipeline = [{
        "$lookup": {    
            "from": "users",
            "localField": "user_id",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "user_id"    
        }
    }, {
        "$match": {
            "user_id": {
                "$size": 0
            }
        }
    }
]

var cursor = db.questions.aggregate(pipeline);
// create a map to get _id of all the question where user doesnt exist
var ids = cursor.map(function (doc) { return doc._id; });
// remove all those questions
db.questions.remove({"_id": { "$in": ids }});
```

Comment: I am doing it in the mongo server

Comment: This is basically the same answer as I gave isn't it?

Comment: I didnt see you had posted an answer while i was writing it. @eol
I had done exactly same for one of my usecase, so i just used that code, updated the code for the OP. I saw your answer when i posted mine. I didnt want to delete it after i saw that my answer is kinda same as yours

Comment: @SugumarVenkatesan The above code should work in Mongo Server as well

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti: I see, no problem - your removal might be even better as mine, since you need only one query.